# Android - Scale TableLayout to Screen Size

Tags: android, xml

I have an Android app that contains a `RelativeLayout` with a `TableLayout` inside of it.

Within the `TableLayout` there are 3 `ImageView`s for each of the 3 `TableLayout` rows. (Making 9 in total)

The problem I'm having is that the last `ImageView` in each row is partially cut off.

This is my current xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".Main">
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:shrinkColumns="true"
            android:id="@+id/TableLayout">
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/s1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"/>
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/s2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"/>
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/s3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"/>
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

(The rest of the rows are the same)

I have tried playing around with values like `fill_parent` and `wrap_content` but I haven't had any success yet.

I would like to scale the `TableLayout` to the size of the screen, so that it looks good on all devices, without any of the images getting cut off.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it cut of at the right or bottom? Could you add a screenshot maybe?

Comment: @RobinF The images are being cut on the right. I'll try to get a screenshot.

Comment: @RobinF I have added a screenshot, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use a `LinearLayout` as the parent and have the `TableLayout` use weights inside, this way your rows and columns will spread evenly by dividing the total space available evenly.

Also in case you want the images to fit the allocated space use `match_parent` both for height and weight with `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for the `ImageViews` inside the `TableLayout`. Other image scaling algorithms are also available so for the best results (to fit into your needs) try and play with it a little bit and see what fits you the most.

Comment: No luck using the `LinearLayout` and scaling the images with `scaleType="fitXY"`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Than add the android:stretchColumns="*" to the tablelayout and try and use a different scaling algorithem, those algorithems are suggested as an autocomplete for the property of the ImageView=>android:scaleType to read more about them you can look in here- 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html